# Changing images on hover with css/html

Tags: html, css, image, hover, mousehover

I have a problem with changing images by hover effect. Actually I can change image if the images are one on the top of the other but I need something different. 
I need to change the images when I mouse over another image. Like;

```
<div id="gallery">
                    <div>
                        <img src="images/team-large.jpg" alt="Img">
                    </div>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <img src="images/elek2.jpg" alt="Img" title="Elektronik Alt Sistemler">
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <img src="images/su.jpg" alt="Img" title="Sualtı Akustik Sistemler">
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <img src="images/yazılım.jpg" alt="Img" title="Yazılım, Bilgi Teknolojileri ve Simülasyon">
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
```

This is my HTML Code and I need to change

```
<img src="images/team-large.jpg" alt="Img">
```

this image when I mouse over the other sub images but I'm stuck.

**Addition;**

How can I change other images by onmouseover and onmouseout commands??

```
    <div id="gallery">
                        <div>
                            <img src="images/team-large.jpg" id="Img1" name="Img1" class="Img1" alt="Img1" />
                        </div>
                        <ul>
                            <li>
                                <img src="images/elek2.jpg" alt="Img" title="Elektronik Alt Sistemler" 
onmouseover="'#Img1'.src='images/elek3.jpg'" onmouseout="'#Img1'.src='images/team-large.jpg'">
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <img src="images/su.jpg" alt="Img" title="Sualtı Akustik Sistemler" class="thumbnail">
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <img src="images/yazılım.jpg" alt="Img" title="Yazılım, Bilgi Teknolojileri ve Simülasyon" class="thumbnail">
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
```

I added the ID name to Img1 and tried to change the image when I mouse over 'images/elek2.jpg' but it doesn't work.

Thanks for help.

Comment: So your goal is to set this "main" image source equal to the image source the user is hovering this moment?

Comment: Exactly the same. @Giorgio

Answer (score 1):

You could alter the background image using css's `:hover` instead. Something like:

```css
div{
  height:200px;
  width:200px;
  background:url("http://placekitten.com/g/200/200");
  }

div:hover{
    background:url("http://placekitten.com/g/200/400");
  }
```

```html
<div></div>
```

---

For what you're looking for, you might need the child or sibling selector:

```css
.parent{
  height:300px;
  width:300px;
  background: url("http://placekitten.com/g/300/300");
  }

.child{
  height:200px;
  width:200px;
  background: url("http://placekitten.com/g/200/200");
  }

.parent:hover .child{
  background: url("http://placekitten.com/g/200/300");
  }
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  
  <div class="child"></div>
```

Comment: yeah I know this way but when I make the image background, it doesn't show up. I don't know why. @jbutler483

Comment: @Burak: Look up the css 'sibling' selector

Comment: I change the question, could you check the new verson please ? @jbutler483

Comment: @Burak: [see this](http://designshack.net/articles/css/swap-your-pages-background-image-on-navigation-hover/) for a step by step guide on doing that.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this jQuery code to change source of main image

```
var original = $('#main').attr('src');

$('.thumbnail').mouseover(function()
{
   var source = $(this).attr('src'); // retrieve image source of hovered image
   $('#main').attr('src', source); // update main image source
})
.mouseout(function() {
   $('#main').attr('src', original); // restore original image source
});
```

[**jsFiddle code (UPDATED)**](http://jsfiddle.net/3bnu4r5t/2/)

In the linked snippet, I've assigned a `main` id to main image and a `thumbnail` class to other images. This allows to access them runtime via jQuery.

Comment: I change the question, could you check the new verson please ? @Giorgio

Comment: I've updated my answer and added mouseout handler. But I'm not sure about to have correctly interpreted your question update. This snippet sets main image to thumbnail on mouse over and set it back to original source on mouse out. Let me know if it is correct.