# Pure css change Big image on hover over thumbnails

Tags: html, css, pure-css

I have this html code:

```
<div class="main-img">
  <img id="main" src="http://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/NjU1WDgwMA==/z/HWIAAOSw8vZXMKGK/$_1.JPG?set_id=880000500F" alt="Teak Cleaner - 1lt bring back the original colour of teak/hardwood - Teak care" class="img-responsive main-image">

  <p class="single-thumbnail-p">
    <img src="http://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/NjU1WDgwMA==/z/HWIAAOSw8vZXMKGK/$_1.JPG?set_id=880000500F" class="img-responsive thumbnail" alt="Teak Cleaner - 1lt bring back the original colour of teak/hardwood - Teak care" />
    <img src="http://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/MTEzMVgxNjAw/z/u8kAAOSw3mpXMKGT/$_1.JPG?set_id=880000500F" class="img-responsive thumbnail" alt="Teak Cleaner - 1lt bring back the original colour of teak/hardwood - Teak care" />
  </p>
</div>
```

What i want to do is change the main image bacground or src using pure css, i know that src can not be changed but is there is any way with which i can change big image on hover of thumbnails ?

Thanks!

Comment: Try this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27961873/changing-images-on-hover-with-css-html)

Comment: You can use CSS background image, but I think use Javascript (or jQuery) is better.

Comment: Using js i can do it pretty easily but thing is js is not allowed only html and css

Comment: Let me know if my answer worked and can be accepted, or else I delete it.

Comment: Thanks not a ideal one as it changes html structure but i think it will help me and alot of others as well  :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both the thumbnails and the main image need to be siblings (or parent/child) for hover to work.

Based on your sample code I assume the `thumbnail`'s should be below, so here I positioned them before the `main-image` in the markup and used absolute to move them below, so CSS hover will work. You can also do this with Flexbox and its order property, though it has less browser support.

```css
.main-img {
  position: relative;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
.main-img .thumbnail {
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  width: 100px;
}
.main-img .main-image {
  display: block;
  height: 200px;
}
.main-img .thumbnail + .thumbnail {
  left: 160px;
}
#main2 {
  display: none;
}
.main-img .thumbnail + .thumbnail:hover ~ #main1 {
  display: none;
}
.main-img .thumbnail + .thumbnail:hover ~ #main2 {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-img">

  <img src="http://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/NjU1WDgwMA==/z/HWIAAOSw8vZXMKGK/$_1.JPG?set_id=880000500F" class="img-responsive thumbnail" alt="Teak Cleaner - 1lt bring back the original colour of teak/hardwood - Teak care" />
  <img src="http://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/MTEzMVgxNjAw/z/u8kAAOSw3mpXMKGT/$_1.JPG?set_id=880000500F" class="img-responsive thumbnail" alt="Teak Cleaner - 1lt bring back the original colour of teak/hardwood - Teak care" />

  <img id="main1" src="http://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/NjU1WDgwMA==/z/HWIAAOSw8vZXMKGK/$_1.JPG?set_id=880000500F" alt="Teak Cleaner - 1lt bring back the original colour of teak/hardwood - Teak care" class="img-responsive main-image">

  <img id="main2" src="http://i.ebayimg.com/00/s/MTEzMVgxNjAw/z/u8kAAOSw3mpXMKGT/$_1.JPG?set_id=880000500F" alt="Teak Cleaner - 1lt bring back the original colour of teak/hardwood - Teak care" class="img-responsive main-image">

</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use background image.Add above three images as background image.then on hover change background.

Comment: Yep thats what i was thinking but how will big  image background will be changed on hover of thumbnail and how will we know which image need to be changed as big image on hover of a thumbnail any clues ?